# Memory Management Flash as3 for iphone and ipad dev

Tags: flash, ios, memory-management

im currently doing an application in flash that i convert so it can be run on a iphone and ipad. Thing is that it gets ridiculously slow after being used for a while, seems like every time i load something in the app, it always stays in ram.

What should a flash developer think of for smarter memory management? The app loads some pictures and some mp3 speaking voice, smart thing would be to unset, release, dealloc things after being used, like in cocoa. Is it possible in flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/optimize_content_ios.html) by Scott Petersen to be very useful.

He talks mostly about optimizing the code and images but I am sure it is a good place to start at the least.